# compare the value of two form email fields

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created a form requiring email validation. So user must type in their email address twice and if they don't match they won't be able to submit. I did this by simply comparing the values of email fields 1 and 2. If they match "disabled" is removed from the submit button.

All was working perfectly when I had the value set to "Insert your email address and "confirm your email address again". However, so that the user does not have to delete that text, I removed the value and used "placeholder" in the HTML instead.

The problem now is that the moment you type anything it's returning as true. I guess it's seeing the blank values as the same, but it's not picking up on the changes to the value as the user types it in.

Why are the two fields always returning as a match?

```
<html>
<body>
  <form class="theForm">
     <p> Subscribe to my mailing list</p>
     <input type="text" id="name" class="fields" name="name" placeholder="Name">
     <input type="text" id="email1" class="fields" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" >
     <input type="text" id="email2" class="fields" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" >
     <input name="submit" id="submit" class="fields" type="submit" disabled value="Email Addresses 
Do Not Match">
  </form>
<script>  
function verify (){

console.log(`email1.value: ${email1}: Email2: ${email2}`);

if(document.getElementById("email1").value === document.getElementById("email2").value) {

document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "#004580";
document.getElementById("submit").style.cursor = "pointer";

} else {
document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
}
$(".fields").on("change paste keyup", verify);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form class="theForm">
     <p> Subscribe to my mailing list</p>
     <input type="text" id="name" class="fields" name="name" placeholder="Name">
     <input type="text" id="email1" class="fields" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" >
     <input type="text" id="email2" class="fields" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" >
     <input id="submit" type="button" onclick="verify()" value="click">
  </form>
  <script>
  function verify()
{
if(document.getElementById("email1").value === document.getElementById("email2").value) {

    alert("matched")

} else {
   document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
   alert("not matched")
  }

}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Change the email inputs to [type='email'].
- Add the required attribute to #email1.
- Add a check to the validity of #email1 in your conditional.
- Reset styles to initial (or what you prefer) if the button is reset back to 'disabled'.
- Use 'input' event to get the the values updating on every keystroke, 'change' only fires on 'blur' or when the form is submitted.

It'd end up looking like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
      <form class="theForm">
         <p> Subscribe to my mailing list</p>
         <input type="text" id="name" class="fields" name="name" placeholder="Name">
         <input type="email" id="email1" class="fields" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
         <input type="email" id="email2" class="fields" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" >
         <input name="submit" id="submit" class="fields" type="submit" disabled value="Email Addresses Do Not Match">
      </form>
    <script>
  
    function verify (){
    
      console.log(`email1: ${email1.value}: Email2: ${email2.value}`);
    
      if(document.getElementById("email1").checkValidity() && document.getElementById("email1").value === document.getElementById("email2").value) {
    
        document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "#004580";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.cursor = "pointer";
    
      } else {

        document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "initial";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.cursor = "initial";

      }
    }

    $(".theForm").on("input paste keyup", "input[type=email]", verify);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

MDN Docs for input and change events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: Please try to make it to point wise instead of paragraphs.

Comment: Amazing! Easy to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(".fields").on("change paste keyup", verify)
```

Try:

```
$(".fields").blur(verify)
```

EDIT:
How about:

```
$("#email2").blur(verify)
```

?

Comment: That sort of works. You can't submit it. So it appears the line to remove "disabled" is working. However, the button color and cursor style still change even if they don't match and that should only change if they do. In other words, the button should be grayed out until the match.

Comment: I've made an edit to the answer, let me know if this one works :)